# Список дисков, подключенных к машине

Tags: диск, linux

Как просмотреть список дисков (то есть /dev/sda, /dev/sdb и так далее), которые присоединены к машине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А еще так:

```
hwinfo --disk --shortdisk:  /dev/sda             SAMSUNG HD103UJ  /dev/sdb             Generic USB SD Reader
```

Чтобы пользоваться, надо установить hwinfo:

```
apt-get install hwinfo
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов несколько:

```
lsblk
df -h
fdisk -l
```

Answer (score 2):

С правами root

fdisk -l